# Too many vmware files on documents

Tags: vmware

I have installed sierra on vmware workstation pro. When I looked up my vmware files on my documents, I recognized that the folder includes lots of vmdk files. Can I delete some of them ?

[image]

Comment: These files are the virtual disk files, if you delete them, you will lose any installed VMs. Simple awnser, if you don't want to delete your MacOS VM, don't delete them.

Comment: How large is your VM hard drive?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Virtual Machine Files article in VMware Workstation Pro Documentation:](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-A968EF50-BA25-450A-9D1F-F8A9DEE640E7.html)

> **vname-s###.vmdk**
>
> If you specified that the files can increase, filenames include an s
> in the file number, for example, Windows 7-s001.vmdk.
>
> If you specified that the virtual disk is divided into 2GB sections,
> the number of files depends on the size of the virtual disk. As data
> is added to a virtual disk, the files increase to a maximum of 2GB
> each.

**In other words:**

Your virtual hard drive(s) are split into multiple discrete files on your hypervisor file system.

Don't delete them.

VMware will manage its own files according to its own rules and taking into account any settings you may have set. Leave them alone.

Comment: You were right. I fixed that.